# How to create a background job with sling commons scheduler in AEM as a Cloud?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I tried 2 ways to do a periodical background job.

1:sling job. This was executed on both local SDK and AEM cloud, but executed many times when the specified time come.

2:commons scheduler. This is good on a local SDK, but this did nothing on AEM cloud environment.

I want to know how can it be executed with second way(Sling Commons Scheduler).

Here is my sample code

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(service = Runnable.class, property = { Scheduler.PROPERTY_SCHEDULER_EXPRESSION + "=0 30 * * * ? " })
public class Myjob implements Runnable {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("this message is from myjob");
    }
}
```

This code above is good on local SDK. On AEM cloud, doesn't work. Please help me.